# e2fsck fails to check root partition while running from ubuntu usb

Tags: live-usb

Even though I booted of a Ubuntu live USB. I keep getting the error:

e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

The root partition I am trying to check is not mounted.
I need to do this so that I can reduce the size of my lvm volume.
How can I overcome this porblem?

```
 Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048   499711   497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 78163967 77662210   37G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 78163967 77662208   37G 8e Linux LVM

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 78156287 78154240 37.3G 8e Linux LVM
```

```
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb                       8:16   0 37.3G  0 disk
└─sdb1                    8:17   0 37.3G  0 part
  └─NAS1-root           253:0    0 73.4G  0 lvm  /
sda                       8:0    0 37.3G  0 disk
├─sda2                    8:2    0    1K  0 part
├─sda5                    8:5    0   37G  0 part
│ ├─NAS1-swap_1         253:1    0  892M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ └─NAS1-root           253:0    0 73.4G  0 lvm  /
└─sda1                    8:1    0  243M  0 part /boot
```

I use sudo -i when I run the e2fsck command. 
When I run the check on sda1 it works ok but when I run it on sda5 and sdb1 it fails. sda5 and sdb1 are part of my lvm VG for root partition.

Comment: Did you use sudo? `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdxn`where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number of your root partition (in the internal drive). The following command will check for bad blocks too, `sudo e2fsck -cf /dev/sdxn` ; See also this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986

Comment: You say "partition" but then mention "lvm" - please [edit] your question to show us your filesystem layout (e.g. output of `lsblk` or `blkid`) and the actual `e2fsck` command you ran

Comment: Good catch @steeldriver :-)